# How does the power output of the 33 Raptors on SpaceX's Superheavy compare to the power distributed on America's electrical grid?

Tags: rockets, power, spacex-super-heavy

I recall hearing somewhere that the Space Shuttle's power was similar to that of the US electrical grid at some point in the past - but that might have been a myth.

If anyone thinks that they know how to do the calculation for Superheavy's power output (with reasonable accuracy) I'd be interested in learning the answer.

For answer-to-answer consistency, let's assume the theoretical maximum ISP for a sea-level MethylOx engine is 299 s, which I found through a link on the [Specific Impulse Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse) in [this article on ROCKET PROPELLANTS](http://www.braeunig.us/space/propel.htm).

[image: ROCKET PROPELLANT PERFORMANCE]
[image]

Let's also assume that the Raptors are 98% efficient (this is a SWAG).

In case this is helpful, I also fit a curve to Starship's orbital flight test 2 data (lift-off to MECO):

> Speed(kph) = 6.2e-4*t^3 + 1.55e-2*t^2 + 1.75e1*t (0<=t<=160)

(Note: I am *not* affiliated with any of the links in this post.)

Answer (score 5):

Let's focus on the energy expended by burning the fuel.

1 mol(16g) of methane has a energy output of 810kJ when burnt in excess oxygen. One watt is one Joule per second. 1kg methane therefore releases 50,625kJ or 50.625MJ of energy. Therefore, burning 134 kg/s results in 6783 MJ per second or 6.78 GW of energy output! For one engine. So this times 33 (the currently planned final engine count for Booster) results in 223.9 GW of energy output! That's quite a bit.

But how does it stack up to the US Energy Grid?
From the Energy Information Administration

> At the end of 2022, the United States had 1,160,169 MW(1160GW)—or about 1.16 billion kW—of total utility-scale electricity-generation capacity and about 39,486 MW—or nearly 0.04 billion kW—of small-scale solar photovoltaic electricity-generation capacity.

So the 33 Raptor Engines combined produce about a fifth of the wattage of the US National Grid. Pretty impressive if you ask me!

Comment: Thanks! Can you add sources for some of your numbers, such as 134 kg/s?

Comment: That would be the theoretical maximum based on the assumption that the Raptors are 100% efficient in converting the combustion energy of methane into power. In reality a huge amount of the energy goes to waste heat. And there are efficiency losses in the nozzle. And there is also unburnt methane that makes it into the exhaust. What is really needed is to covert the Raptor thrust into watts, but since force and power are not the same thing that's not a straightforward calculation.

Comment: Just to be clear, unburned methane doesn't "make it into" the exhaust; the rocket intentionally runs fuel-rich (as do most rockets) for a variety of technical reasons. I don't think we can look at the methane usage and derive power output by just assuming it all burns. We know it doesn't.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym - thanks for adding, I was going to mention the fuel rich ratio but decided not to for brevity since that's not the only reason not all of the fuel burns, even at stoichiometric not all of the fuel combusts because combustion chambers aren't perfect. But yes I would think the fuel rich mixture is the biggest contributor to unburnt fuel.

Comment: This answer shows that the power output of the 33 Raptor engines at liftoff is probably within one to two orders of magnitude of the power of the entire US electricity grid. Getting an exact number is not necessary for understanding the scale.

Comment: @WaterMolecule - I think you're probably right. A general guesstimate for rocket efficiency is about 65%. Compared to 100% efficiency that's a colossal difference in gigawatts. However to your point it's the difference between 1/5th of the power grid and 1/8th of the grid, which conceptually gets the point across. Interestingly I came across a quote from a former Shuttle SSME engineer who claims to be the one who calculated 23 Hoover Dams of power from the SSME's, often quoted by NASA. But a NASA website that I found states 13 Hoover Dams. Yes in that context 10 Hoover Dams is just a quibble.

Comment: It does depend on what you compare to what. Rocket brute output or effective thrust v total installed electrical capacity or actual operational output at any time. It more like a Germany than a USA...

Comment: You guys are right, this answer isnt perfect, I'll do some more calculation when I have the time and update :)

Comment: An earlier answer (now deleted) used the value of 4,271.88 TWh/year (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_sector_of_the_United_States) which I think works out to 487 GW for the US grid. Can you update that part of your answer so that it matches the question better, which says "the power distributed on America's electrical grid" and not "electricity generation capacity"? Note: technically we should account for distribution losses too. Intent here was to compare the power *output* of Superheavy to the average power *output* of the national grid, not input to output or input to input.